# remove repeated text in the anchor tag inner html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some part of the text is repeated in the anchor tag inner html.

```
<a href="" class="abc">There is some text some text some text some text </a>
```

But I want the output to remove duplicate text.

required output

```
<a href="" class="abc">There is some text</a>
```

How to remove repeated text in the anchor tag inner html? the word 'some text' is repeated in few pages. I just need to get rid off 'some text' occuring many times. I would need to go through all the anchor tags in a page and remove the word 'some text' if it appears more than once.

Comment: Maybe you could change it before it is outputed rather than using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

The script can be written like this:

```js
 var a = "There is some text some text some text some text";
 var unique = [];
 (a.split(' ')).forEach(function(text) {
   if (unique.indexOf(text) < 0) {
     unique.push(text);
   }
 });
 document.write(unique.join(' '));
```

you can now try to put it inside your `<a>` tag